# MS Word Captions of Figures, Tables, Equations are not transferred in "insert Caption drop down list" when file is opened in another computer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I prepared a MS-Word document in Office 2013. All the Figures, Captions of all the Tables and Equations are properly inserted and crossed referred in the document. The list of Tables and List of Figures are also properly generated and cross-reference links are working fine.

However, when I sent the file to another computer, installed with Office 2016, still the cross-referred links are working (By pressing the Ctrl button and clicking the cross-referred Figure/Table/Equation). But when I try to insert another Figure or Equation, by using the "insert caption" option, the drop-down list does not contain customized labels like "Eq.". Moreover, the "Figure" and "Table" are there by default, but when I select them, the "caption" field does not show the number like Eq. 2.1, it's totally empty, not even the label itself.

I checked the cross-reference options to see if in the list of "Reference Type" there are Tables, Figures and Eq., but there are no Tables and Eq. available.

I hope I explained the issue in detail. I am stuck and looking for a workable solution to get out of this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The custom labels for Captions are not part of the document but rather saved on each computer. On the new computer, they need to be recreated. The advantage of this is that when you are working on another document, you do not need to recreate them.

Under Cross-Reference, or the Table of Figures, it is not using those custom labels but rather the ones already found in the document.

Here is the [part of my chapter on Complex Documents dealing with insertion of Captions](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqTZzjvx6q9zmXkOwfGDKa-ccnCx?e=vUUC2z).